# ¿Cómo solucionar error al conectar aplicación con el servidor local de sql server 2014?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo una aplicación en C# y en ella utilizo el siguiente código para conectarme con la base de datos alojada en sql server 2014:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=MAQUINA15-PC/SQLEXPRESS;
Initial Catalog=BDEjemlo;Persist Security Info=True;
User ID=sa;Password=***********";
```

Pero al ejecutar la aplicacción me sale un error.

El mensaje que aparece es el siguiente:

> "Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se
>   establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el
>   servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la
>   instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir
>   conexiones remotas. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - No se
>   pudo abrir una conexión con SQL Server)"

E intentado cambiando el "/" por un "\", tambien intente cambiar el nombre del servidor por la IP de la máquina y el error continua.

Cabe resaltar que tanto visual estudio (entorno en el que estoy desarrollando mi app) y SQL Server estan instalados en la misma máquina.

Comment: y tenes habilitado el sql server para que reciba conexiones?? parece algun error con el connectionstring. lo probaste de alguna otra forma??

Comment: ¿Aunque no sea una conexión remota es necesario activar que reciba ese tipo de conexiones? y si, ya lo he intentado de un par de formas diferentes, me sale el mismo error

Comment: yo probaria activando conexiones remotas

Comment: ¿Cómo las activo?

Comment: Mi pregunta no esta duplicada, es el mismo error pero en circunstancias diferentes

Comment: Intentaste con la IP?

Comment: si ya intenté con la IP y me regresa el mismo error

Comment: si probaste las dos soluciones que estan en esa respuesta, por favor aclaralo. Tratamos de ayudarte con la poca informacion que tenemos. Al no estar fisicamente ahi no es facil saber que pasa.

Comment: ¿Ambas computadoras pertenecen a la misma red?

Comment: Mira si tienes conexión a MAQUINA15-PC usando PING MAQUINA15-PC o tambien PING x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x = la dirección ip). Si no responde, prueba desactivar el firewall en ambas máquinas (solo mientras pruebas). Si al desactivar el firewall funciona, actívalo de nuevo y agrega una regla para permitir el tráfico como dice este artículo: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas utilizando slash `/` cuando deberia de ser backslash `\`:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=MAQUINA15-PC\SQLEXPRESS...";
```

Comment: Si pongo el backslash " \ " me marca error. (se subraya de color rojo )

Comment: Agregale una arroba al string delante para que escape la barra invertida. Mira la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Quisiera agregar que el VS2017 ya no es requerido darle scape a la barra invertida.

Comment: Efectivamente el error se solucionó agregando el " @ " y el " \ "... Gracias

Comment: Creo que también funciona usando doble backslash
"Data Source=MAQUINA15-PC\\SQLEXPRESS..."; y sin usar la "@"

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo hoy he decidido venir buscar solucion al mismo problema y en efecto, se soluciono agregando \\ a la adena de conexion. Gracias!